# Why is my json get request not working?

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on building a movie search app. It is my first time using json.  I cannot figure out why my code is not working. I have it running on localhost using xampp.
 On submit

```
$('.search-form').submit(function (evt) {
        // body...
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $searchBar = $('#search');
        var omdbApi = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?';
        var movieSearchTerm = $searchBar.val();
        var searchData = {
            s:movieSearchTerm,
            r:json
    }
```

Here is the callback function

```
 function displayMovies(data) {
        // for each search result
        $.each(data.items,function(i,movie) {
        movieHTML += '<li class="desc">';
        //movie title
        movieHTML += '<a href="' + movie.Title + '" class="movie-title">';
        //release year
        movieHTML += '<a href="' + movie.Year + '" class="movie-year">';
        //poster
        movieHTML += '<img src="' + movie.Poster + '" class="movie-poster"></li>';
        $('#movies').html(movieHTML);
      }); // end each
      // movieHTML += '</li>'; 
    }
    $.getJSON(omdbApi, searchData, displayMovies);
});//end submit
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your javascript console ?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Do you get any error? Thanks

Comment: These are the errors I am getting: app.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (app.js:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)

Comment: jquery.js:358Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Function.each (jquery.js:358)
    at Object.displayMovies [as success] (VM86 app.js:13)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at x (jquery.js:9314)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:9718)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> r:json
> ```

You made a typo.

You haven't created a variable called `json` and the service expects the value of `r` to be *json*.

String literals need to be surrounded with a pair of `"` or `'`.

> ```
> data.items
> ```

And the JSON returned doesn't have `items`, it has `Search`.